# nginx rewrite mybb to wbb

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, mybb

we are in the middle of a migration from mybb to wbb
and therefore I would need to rewrite the following URLs using nginx:

1st rule

from: somedomain/forum-123.html => 
to: somedomain/board/123/

2nd rule

from: somedomain/thread-1234-post-12345.html => 
to: somedomain/thread/1234/?postID=12345

Can someone help me with those rewrite rules?

Thanks and
many regards

PS: sorry for the bad syntax. but i don't have any reputation and wasnt able to post some "example" links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/forum-([0-9]+)\.html {
    return 301 /board/$1/;
}

location ~ ^/thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html {
    return 301 /thread/$1/?postID=$2;
}
```

This will send permanent redirect replies, which means browsers should assume that the content has moved for good and that they may update bookmarks and such automatically.